# How to make httpgd work in VS Code's debugging mode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

To use VS Code for coding in R I installed [httpgd](https://github.com/nx10/httpgd).

When I start R from a command shell console and run the following [test](https://nx10.github.io/httpgd/articles/a01_how-to-get-started.html) code, everything works well.

```
library(httpgd)

hgd()
hgd_browse()

x = seq(0, 3 * pi, by = 0.1)
plot(x, sin(x), type = "l")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
```

I get this output:
[image: output successful]

However, when I run the code from a file test.R via the VS Code Debugger (F5), I only get part of the output. In the debug console, I get

```
.vsc.debugSource("~/path/to/dir/test.R")
httpgd server running at:
  http://127.0.0.1:53293/live?token=6I50WzYu
Want to understand how all the pieces fit together? Read R for Data
Science: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/
```

In the browser there is only the first graph, but not the second, and I cannot maximise the image by clicking on it.
[image]

When I close the Debugger I sometimes saw something like `Error in .Internal(quit(save, status, runLast)) : invalid connection`.

Is `httpgd` supposed to work with VS Code Debugging?